# javascript regex to match string contain arabic special characters symbols 'ـ' u0640

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need a javascript regex that will find Arabic text containing 'ـ', for example:

If I search for this word: `الله`

The output will find: `الله`

or `اللـه`

or `الـله`

or `الـلـه`

to use it with the next script for highlighting text.

See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/12/).

---

Update:
let's say I want to search in English this string:

"hollow"

I want a regex able to find word:
"hollow" also to find word contain this symbol 'ـ'
which in Unicode is u0640 for example:

**"hـoـlـlـoـw"**

or repeated

**"hـــoـــــlــــlــــoـــــw"**

now the script I mentioned before can find and highlight diacritic and non diacritic text in Arabic and also accent and non accent sensitive in English

For example the script can find :

Text with diacritic :
**"وَوَصَّيْنَا الْإِنسَانَ بِوَالِدَيْهِ إِحْسَانًا ۖ حَمَلَتْهُ"**

same text without diacritic:
**"ووصينا الإِنسان بوالديه إِحسانا حملته"**

Also English with accent insensitivity:

**"séléction"** : can find it

**"SELECTION"** : can find it too small capital letter doesn't matter

by using xregex I'm able to accomplish it with mapping by this code:

```
 var charToAccentedCharClassMap = {
// for arabic
"\u0623":'([\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623])',
"\u0627":'([\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623])',
"\u0625":'([\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623])',
"\u0622":'([\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0627\u0625\u0622\u0623])',
"\u06D6":'(\u06D6\\p{Mn}+|\u06D6)',
"\u0628":'(\u0628\\p{Mn}+|\u0628)',
"\u062A":'(\u062A\\p{Mn}+|\u062A)',
"\u062B":'(\u062B\\p{Mn}+|\u062B)',
"\u062C":'(\u062C\\p{Mn}+|\u062C)',
"\u062D":'(\u062D\\p{Mn}+|\u062D)',
"\u062E":'(\u062E\\p{Mn}+|\u062E)', 
"\u062F":'(\u062F\\p{Mn}+|\u062F)',
"\u0630":'(\u0630\\p{Mn}+|\u0630)',
"\u0631":'(\u0631\\p{Mn}+|\u0631)',
"\u0632":'(\u0632\\p{Mn}+|\u0632)',
"\u0633":'(\u0633\\p{Mn}+|\u0633)',
"\u0634":'(\u0634\\p{Mn}+|\u0634)',
"\u0635":'(\u0635\\p{Mn}+|\u0635)',
"\u0636":'(\u0636\\p{Mn}+|\u0636)',
"\u0637":'(\u0637\\p{Mn}+|\u0637)',
"\u0638":'(\u0638\\p{Mn}+|\u0638)',
"\u0639":'(\u0639\\p{Mn}+|\u0639)',
"\u063A":'(\u063A\\p{Mn}+|\u063A)',
"\u0641":'(\u0641\\p{Mn}+|\u0641)',
"\u0642":'(\u0642\\p{Mn}+|\u0642)',
"\u0643":'(\u0643\\p{Mn}+|\u0643)',
"\u0644":'(\u0644\\p{Mn}+|\u0644)',
"\u0645":'(\u0645\\p{Mn}+|\u0645)',
"\u0646":'(\u0646\\p{Mn}+|\u0646)',
"\u0647":'(\u0647\\p{Mn}+|\u0647)',
"\u064A":'(\u064A\\p{Mn}+|\u064A)',
"\u0649":'(\u0649\\p{Mn}+|\u0649)',
"\u0626":'(\u0626\\p{Mn}+|\u0626)',
"\u0621":'(\u0621\\p{Mn}+|\u0621)',
"\u0629":'(\u0629\\p{Mn}+|\u0629)',
"\u0648":'([\u0624\u0648]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0624\u0648])',
"\u0624":'([\u0624\u0648]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0624\u0648])',
"\u0640":'([\u0640]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0640])',
  // for other languages
'A':'[Aa\xaa\xc0\xc5\xe0\xe5\u0100\u0105\u01cd\u01ce\u0200\u0203\u0226\u0227\u1d2c\u1d43\u1e00\u1e01\u1e9a\u1ea0\u1ea3\u2090\u2100\u2101\u213b\u249c\u24b6\u24d0\u3371\u3374\u3380\u3384\u3388\u3389\u33a9\u33af\u33c2\u33ca\u33df\u33ff\uff21\uff41]',
'B' : '[Bb\u1d2e\u1d47\u1e02-\u1e07\u212c\u249d\u24b7\u24d1\u3374\u3385-\u3387\u33c3\u33c8\u33d4\u33dd\uff22\uff42]',
'C' : '[Cc\xc7\xe7\u0106-\u010d\u1d9c\u2100\u2102\u2103\u2105\u2106\u212d\u216d\u217d\u249e\u24b8\u24d2\u3376\u3388\u3389\u339d\u33a0\u33a4\u33c4-\u33c7\uff23\uff43]',
'D' : '[Dd\u010e\u010f\u01c4-\u01c6\u01f1-\u01f3\u1d30\u1d48\u1e0a-\u1e13\u2145\u2146\u216e\u217e\u249f\u24b9\u24d3\u32cf\u3372\u3377-\u3379\u3397\u33ad-\u33af\u33c5\u33c8\uff24\uff44]',
'E' : '[Ee\xc8-\xcb\xe8-\xeb\u0112-\u011b\u0204-\u0207\u0228\u0229\u1d31\u1d49\u1e18-\u1e1b\u1eb8-\u1ebd\u2091\u2121\u212f\u2130\u2147\u24a0\u24ba\u24d4\u3250\u32cd\u32ce\uff25\uff45]',
'F' : '[Ff\u1da0\u1e1e\u1e1f\u2109\u2131\u213b\u24a1\u24bb\u24d5\u338a-\u338c\u3399\ufb00-\ufb04\uff26\uff46]',
'G' : '[Gg\u011c-\u0123\u01e6\u01e7\u01f4\u01f5\u1d33\u1d4d\u1e20\u1e21\u210a\u24a2\u24bc\u24d6\u32cc\u32cd\u3387\u338d-\u338f\u3393\u33ac\u33c6\u33c9\u33d2\u33ff\uff27\uff47]',
'H' : '[Hh\u0124\u0125\u021e\u021f\u02b0\u1d34\u1e22-\u1e2b\u1e96\u210b-\u210e\u24a3\u24bd\u24d7\u32cc\u3371\u3390-\u3394\u33ca\u33cb\u33d7\uff28\uff48]',
'I' : '[Ii\xcc-\xcf\xec-\xef\u0128-\u0130\u0132\u0133\u01cf\u01d0\u0208-\u020b\u1d35\u1d62\u1e2c\u1e2d\u1ec8-\u1ecb\u2071\u2110\u2111\u2139\u2148\u2160-\u2163\u2165-\u2168\u216a\u216b\u2170-\u2173\u2175-\u2178\u217a\u217b\u24a4\u24be\u24d8\u337a\u33cc\u33d5\ufb01\ufb03\uff29\uff49]',
'J' : '[Jj\u0132-\u0135\u01c7-\u01cc\u01f0\u02b2\u1d36\u2149\u24a5\u24bf\u24d9\u2c7c\uff2a\uff4a]',
'K' : '[Kk\u0136\u0137\u01e8\u01e9\u1d37\u1d4f\u1e30-\u1e35\u212a\u24a6\u24c0\u24da\u3384\u3385\u3389\u338f\u3391\u3398\u339e\u33a2\u33a6\u33aa\u33b8\u33be\u33c0\u33c6\u33cd-\u33cf\uff2b\uff4b]',
'L' : '[Ll\u0139-\u0140\u01c7-\u01c9\u02e1\u1d38\u1e36\u1e37\u1e3a-\u1e3d\u2112\u2113\u2121\u216c\u217c\u24a7\u24c1\u24db\u32cf\u3388\u3389\u33d0-\u33d3\u33d5\u33d6\u33ff\ufb02\ufb04\uff2c\uff4c]',
'M' : '[Mm\u1d39\u1d50\u1e3e-\u1e43\u2120\u2122\u2133\u216f\u217f\u24a8\u24c2\u24dc\u3377-\u3379\u3383\u3386\u338e\u3392\u3396\u3399-\u33a8\u33ab\u33b3\u33b7\u33b9\u33bd\u33bf\u33c1\u33c2\u33ce\u33d0\u33d4-\u33d6\u33d8\u33d9\u33de\u33df\uff2d\uff4d]',
'N' : '[Nn\xd1\xf1\u0143-\u0149\u01ca-\u01cc\u01f8\u01f9\u1d3a\u1e44-\u1e4b\u207f\u2115\u2116\u24a9\u24c3\u24dd\u3381\u338b\u339a\u33b1\u33b5\u33bb\u33cc\u33d1\uff2e\uff4e]',
'O' : '[Oo\xba\xd2-\xd6\xf2-\xf6\u014c-\u0151\u01a0\u01a1\u01d1\u01d2\u01ea\u01eb\u020c-\u020f\u022e\u022f\u1d3c\u1d52\u1ecc-\u1ecf\u2092\u2105\u2116\u2134\u24aa\u24c4\u24de\u3375\u33c7\u33d2\u33d6\uff2f\uff4f]',
'P' : '[Pp\u1d3e\u1d56\u1e54-\u1e57\u2119\u24ab\u24c5\u24df\u3250\u3371\u3376\u3380\u338a\u33a9-\u33ac\u33b0\u33b4\u33ba\u33cb\u33d7-\u33da\uff30\uff50]',
'Q' : '[Qq\u211a\u24ac\u24c6\u24e0\u33c3\uff31\uff51]',
'R' : '[Rr\u0154-\u0159\u0210-\u0213\u02b3\u1d3f\u1d63\u1e58-\u1e5b\u1e5e\u1e5f\u20a8\u211b-\u211d\u24ad\u24c7\u24e1\u32cd\u3374\u33ad-\u33af\u33da\u33db\uff32\uff52]',
'S' : '[Ss\u015a-\u0161\u017f\u0218\u0219\u02e2\u1e60-\u1e63\u20a8\u2101\u2120\u24ae\u24c8\u24e2\u33a7\u33a8\u33ae-\u33b3\u33db\u33dc\ufb06\uff33\uff53]',
'T' : '[Tt\u0162-\u0165\u021a\u021b\u1d40\u1d57\u1e6a-\u1e71\u1e97\u2121\u2122\u24af\u24c9\u24e3\u3250\u32cf\u3394\u33cf\ufb05\ufb06\uff34\uff54]',
'U' : '[Uu\xd9-\xdc\xf9-\xfc\u0168-\u0173\u01af\u01b0\u01d3\u01d4\u0214-\u0217\u1d41\u1d58\u1d64\u1e72-\u1e77\u1ee4-\u1ee7\u2106\u24b0\u24ca\u24e4\u3373\u337a\uff35\uff55]',
'V' : '[Vv\u1d5b\u1d65\u1e7c-\u1e7f\u2163-\u2167\u2173-\u2177\u24b1\u24cb\u24e5\u2c7d\u32ce\u3375\u33b4-\u33b9\u33dc\u33de\uff36\uff56]',
'W' : '[Ww\u0174\u0175\u02b7\u1d42\u1e80-\u1e89\u1e98\u24b2\u24cc\u24e6\u33ba-\u33bf\u33dd\uff37\uff57]',
'X' : '[Xx\u02e3\u1e8a-\u1e8d\u2093\u213b\u2168-\u216b\u2178-\u217b\u24b3\u24cd\u24e7\u33d3\uff38\uff58]',
'Y' : '[Yy\xdd\xfd\xff\u0176-\u0178\u0232\u0233\u02b8\u1e8e\u1e8f\u1e99\u1ef2-\u1ef9\u24b4\u24ce\u24e8\u33c9\uff39\uff59]',
'Z' : '[Zz\u0179-\u017e\u01f1-\u01f3\u1dbb\u1e90-\u1e95\u2124\u2128\u24b5\u24cf\u24e9\u3390-\u3394\uff3a\uff5a]'
};
```

then I improved the script to find strings contain symbols between words only ignoring the first and end of the whole string:

For example:

if I typed : **"hello world"**

the result will find:

**"hello world"**

**"hello <>:;'".,#%^@)( world"**

using this code:

```
 var inputPattern = XRegExp('('+input.split(' ').join('[\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}\\p{m}]+')+')',"g");
```

p{p} :will find all Punctuation

p{S} : will find all symbols

p{m}  : will find all diacritics

The last thing left is to find away to let the script be able to find words
contain one special character 'ـ' which is used in some quranic Arabic text

For example:

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم**

when add 'ـ' it will be :

**بـــسم الــلــه الرحمـــن الرحيــــــم**

I couldn't figure out how to do it.

See in action how the script works:

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/19/).

---

**Solved thanks to trincot**
here is the final result :

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/20/).

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include specifically what you've developed so far for the regex? Demos are nice but there's a lot of JS in there to go through.

Comment: You should also assume that your audience knows nothing about the Arabic alphabet. I don't see anything containing '-', for example, and don't know what the significance of those characters above are, in relation to a hyphen.

Comment: hi i updated the post explaining in more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the following regex pattern after every non-space character: `\u0640*`. It will allow any number of tatweel characters to occur after any non-space character.

You already perform a match on non-space characters with this call:

```
var regexp = cleanString.replace(/\S/g, accentReplacer);
```

So the function `accentReplacer` is probably the best place to apply this modification:

```
var accentReplacer = function(character) {
    var h = charToAccentedCharClassMap[character] || character;
    return h + '\u0640*';
};
```

Comment: thank you so much my friend you helped me a lot it's working very nice

Comment: one last thing if want to detect diacritic in tataweel characters i tried this but didn't work :  return h + '(\u0640\p{Mn}|\u0640)*';

Comment: never mind i solved it like this : return h + '([\u0640]\\p{Mn}+|[\u0640])*';   thanks